# Programmatically adding string.concat

Tags: vb.net

For a side project I need to make this function work. Basically what I need is to concat strings for each string returned from a list (of strings)

```
For Each art As String In artikli

Next

'This part below should be programatically changed String.Concat()
Dim QueryString As String = String.Concat(query, ";", query2, ";", query3, ";", query4)
```

Each 'art' in 'Artikli' is a string (query) which I need to concat.

There can be any number of strings in 'Artikli'

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
Dim QueryString As String = String.Join(";", artikli)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
    Dim artikli() As String = {"Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3"}
    Dim QueryString As String = ""
    For Each art As String In artikli
        QueryString += String.Concat(art, ";")
    Next
```